Powershell not escaping special characters for password
all, I am working on a script to bulk create local users which works fine except for the password creation portion. The script pulls the information from a csv, but when I test the account with the password I think it should be using, it fails. I sense it is due to the special characters not being parsed. Here is a sample password I have in the csv password column.
Passw0rdforSDSSc1entist$2024
I tried with single quotes 'Passw0rdforSDSSc1entist$2024' and double quotes "Passw0rdforSDSSc1entist$2024", as well as putting the escape () before the $, Passw0rdforSDSSc1entist$2024 but still does not work.
# Set variables
$csvFile = "C:\Temp2\Manage_Local_Accounts\Local_Accounts.csv"
$group = "SDS Scientists"

# Import CSV file
$users = Import-Csv $csvFile

# Loop through each user in CSV file
foreach ($user in $users) {
  # Set username and password
  $username = $user.username
  $password = $user.password
  $fullname = $user.FullName

  # Create new user
  $userObj = New-LocalUser -Name $username -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force) -FullName $fullname -Description "Created to use with Sequence Detection Software " -PasswordNeverExpires:$false

  # Set "User must change password at next logon" option
  net user $username /logonpasswordchg:No

  # Add user to group
  Add-LocalGroupMember -Group $group -Member $username
} 


Please post short script and CSV samples that contain only the minimum amount of code needed to reproduce the problem. (Remember, nobody can see your code or your screen!)

I tried to post the code, but this formatting always gets me, but I will try again

@user330183 I re-formatted your code, please check that it's rendered correctly now

How do you "test the account with the password you think it should be using"? Is that with the password hardcoded into another powershell script (e.g. $password = "Passw0rdforSDSSc1entist$2024"", because that might be where the problem is. Can you post the code you're using to test the password? The "User must change password at next logon" might also be problematic if the method you're testing with doesn't change the password at logon...

The passwords are in the CSV file in a column named password. I test the password by doing a run as different user, then try to use the password from the csv file. Unless I am missing the option, I do not see how or where I can upload the CSV file. But to try and give a visual, there are three columns with headers, UserName, Password and FullName. In the password column, I have that password in there. I run the script and it completes without error. It creates the account, moves it to the correct group, but when I test the password it does not work. I set the flag to No for change at logon.

The code you have given is working.
Are you sure your new user has enough permissions to perform operation "runas"? If you want to check the validity of your password, the most efficient way is to log in as that user. If you want to check passwords automatically, you can use the following script:
Add-Type -assemblyname system.DirectoryServices.accountmanagement 
$DS = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext([System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType]::Machine)
$DS.ValidateCredentials("$username", "$password")

To verify character translation, you can also decrypt secure string:
$secure = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force
$BSTR = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($secure)
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)


OMG, you are right, I totally forgot that the new security policies in place has locked down many practices. That makes sense that the error I was getting was not bad password error, but rather "the system cannot find the path specified" when trying to run notepad as the user. Thanks for bringing that to my attention. I also learned two new tricks with those two pieces of code you shared, thanks for that. Now need to learn how to use both haha.

Tested, by logging as the test user and password, and was successful. Still trying to understand how to use the two pieces of code, but I keep fiddling till get it, thanks for everything.
